# device rotation iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation

All of my widths, heights, positions and everything are set relative to views and such, so if the iphone is rotated it should "expand to fit" as it were. :)

How would I go about telling the iphone to be in "landscape mode" ie: refresh, but now all widths are heights and all heights are widths?

Thanks
Tom

**EDIT**
Here is the code I currently have... it still doesn't work - I can't seem to figure out how to make it work

In my view controller (not the root view controller) I have this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

(i have also tried putting this method into my **root** view controller, but that didn't work either)

Then in my `viewDidLoad` method I have this:

```
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

This doesn't work. :( at least not in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `AutoresizingMask` of your view according to what you expect.

or implement the `layoutSubViews` method.

Also, don't forget to implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of the viewControllers.  The flow is as follow.

- Device rotate
- root ViewController receive the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` event
- If the viewController respond YES, the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` event is send to the controllers
- the controller resizes its view according to its `autoresizingMask`
- if the view's `autoresizesSubviews` property is true, the process drill down to the subviews
- `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation` event is sent to the controller.

Here is a sample viewController code

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView* theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UIView* redRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    redRectangle.tag = 1;
    redRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [theView addSubview:redRectangle];
    [redRectangle release];

    UIView* greenRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 120.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    greenRectangle.tag = 2;
    greenRectangle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    greenRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [theView addSubview:greenRectangle];
    [greenRectangle release];

    UIView* yellowRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(theView.bounds.size.width-110.0f, theView.bounds.size.height-110.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    yellowRectangle.tag = 3;
    yellowRectangle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    yellowRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [theView addSubview:yellowRectangle];
    [yellowRectangle release];

    self.view = theView;
    [theView release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: how do i rotate all the content?

Comment: You don't :-) Since the status bar will always be up, the content is resized and does not really "rotate".

Comment: hi... thanks for all your help - I still can't seem to get it to work. :( I'm not sure I'm understanding you properly - I have edited my OP to include what I've done given my understanding of your answer. Sorry if this is tedious.

Comment: thanks for your help - after some more research i found out it was because i was using a UITabBarController - which won't auto rotate unless ALL the root view controllers autorotate. :p thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size of your view automatically by setting :

```
[ tmpView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ];
```

So when you rotate it will resize itself.

But I think it won't do what you need.
So maybe you should add a function (in controller) which is called when device rotate :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [ self refreshLayouts ];

}
```

Then in refreshLayouts you change yourself the width/height like you want.

Good Luck !

Comment: hey. thanks for your help - have edited my op because i still can't seem to get it to work. :( any ideas what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your view controller's call back methods for rotation events are being called or not:

```
-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

If these are not called, then there is no point in going further because your viewController is not rotated at all!

This interests me - **"In my view controller (not the root view controller)"**. How are you adding your view controller to the window hierarchy? Are you presenting it, or just adding its view as a sub-view to, say a root view controller?

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:thePageIWantToAutoRotate animated:YES];` will try those methods, thank you.

Comment: If you are doing it this way, then the contents SHOULD rotate, maybe they appear as clipped, but the view controller should rotate.